# Overwrite Excel File with adding new data for every time save

Tags: excel-2007

I have a code like below that generate an Excel file for my record, I want to do like every time i run my program it will check the last row used, if last row is not null then it will insert the new data in the new row. However, with my code is not getting the desired result. Anyone can help me with this? Thanks

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xla = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
        string file = "TestingAccounts.xls";
        Workbook wb = new Workbook();
        Worksheet ws = new Worksheet();

        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        try
        {
            wb = xla.Workbooks.Open(file, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
            ws = (Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            xla.Workbooks.Open(file);

            Range last = ws.Cells.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeLastCell, Type.Missing);
            Range range = ws.get_Range("A1", last);

            int lastUsedRow = last.Row + 1;
            ws.Cells[lastUsedRow, 1] = "abc";

            xla.DisplayAlerts = false;
            wb.SaveAs(file, XlFileFormat.xlAddIn, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            wb.Close(true, misValue, misValue);

            xla.Quit();

            releaseObject(ws);
            releaseObject(wb);
            releaseObject(xla);
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The excel file is not exist. Click ok to create new one");
            wb = xla.Workbooks.Add(XlSheetType.xlWorksheet);
            ws = (Worksheet)xla.ActiveSheet;

            xla.DisplayAlerts = false;
            wb.SaveAs(file, XlFileFormat.xlAddIn, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing,
            Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            wb.Close(true, misValue, misValue);

            xla.Quit();

            releaseObject(ws);
            releaseObject(wb);
            releaseObject(xla);

        }
```

Assume my above code want to add "abc" in next line if last used row is found not empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is VBA code, but you should get the gist of the solution. Loop through the cells until you find a blank one and insert the data there.  The keys to the solution are a) setting a Range object equal to some starting cell in your sheet ("A1" in the case of this example) and b)  looping through the cells by offsetting each row using Range.Offset(1,0) to "move" one row.

```
' select start range
Set rangePaste = Range("A1")

' loop until you find a blank cell in column A
Do Until rangePaste.Value = ""
  Set rangePaste = rangePaste.Offset(1, 0) ' move down row
Loop

'set cell value
rangePaste.Value = "abc"
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I'm gonna try it out! Btw, could you help me to solve the problem with checking if the excel is already exist and create a new one otherwise because the code above is facing an error when trying to do this.

Comment: You can use the .NET System.IO namespace and do a if(File.Exists(fileName)).